# failed to install powershell 5 on windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell

trying to work with flutter on windows 7 machine turn out it needs Powershell 5, 
did install .net framework 4.5 and Windows Management Framework 5.1.

[screenshot of get-host output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iC6c.jpg):
[image]
 and
[.net related tools installed on the pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tMTz.jpg):
[image]

Comment: What's the output from $PSVersionTable.PSVersion ?

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/a/YAJH2Eo)

Comment: Did you reboot after installing WMF5.1?

Comment: yes i did thats why im so confused

Comment: It looks as if WMF didn't install properly.

Comment: Do you have Windows 7 service pack 1? You can check this in Powershell by using this command `GET-WMIOBJECT win32_operatingsystem | SELECT-OBJECT Name,ServicePackMajorVersion,ServicePackMinorVersion`

Comment: thnx guy but prblem was due to ExecutionPolicy being restriced changed it to remote solved the issue